# Logstash not able to find error log file

Tags: logstash

I implement logstash on my server, now my path has two log files one is named as _info.log and other name as _error.log. I want logstash to read only _error.log. I also specify the path like thin in filebeat.yml file `- /home/PS213-28961/logs/2018-06-12_error.log` but it still read the _info.log file. How to resolve this issue
filebeat.yml

```
filebeat:
prospectors:
paths:
- /home/PS213-28961/logs/2018-06-12_error.log
input_type: log
```

rest of the code

Comment: how do you know its reading _info.log? are you checking elasticsearch?

Comment: on kibana view it shows source anyfile_info.log

Comment: after modifying your filebeat configuration you need to erase your logs from elasticsearch and reboot logstash

Comment: @SufiyanGhori will try it.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori will you please tell me where i can find the ES logs to erase them

Comment: i am sorry, not the logs, but actual elasticsearch index. 
can you please show us your logstash config ?

Comment: you can read here how to delete index, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/indices-delete-index.html